# Delete all files in \bin directories using the Windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I want to clean up my binary files in my development directory.  Is there a way I can recurse through the directory structure and delete all files that are in a `bin` directory using the Windows command line?  (I am using Windows 7.)

Per Nathan, I tried to make a batch `foo.bat`:

```
@ECHO OFF 
for /R %%x in (.) do call:myExistFunc %%x 
GOTO:EOF 
:myExistFunc 
if exist %~1\.\bin call:myDeleteFunc %%~1\bin 
GOTO:EOF 
:myDeleteFunc 
echo. Deleting files from %~1 
del %~1*.* /Q
```

...and this worked.

Comment: @MarcB, that is not what I am looking for.  Starting from a specific directory, I am looking to delete all files that exist in a `bin` directory anywhere in the tree.

Comment: then you should say that up front, instead of rejecting perfectly valid answers for the question you DID ask. How about "find `bin` directories anywhere in a filesystem and delete their contents".

Comment: @MarcB, please reread the question.  The key word "recurse" should be noted.

Comment: Yes, and? You didn't say "recurse to find a `bin` directory". You just said "recurse", so the rest of us are taking it to mean you want to go through a `bin dir and recursively delete its contents. Given you've gotten my comment + 2 actual answers making the same "mistake", accept that your phrasing was bad.

Comment: "recurse through the directory structure and delete all files that are in a `bin` directory" means exactly one thing; I am sorry you did not understand, but the language is clear and precisely what I want to do.

Comment: As currently shown, your batch file has the last three lines merged together on a single line, is this just a transcription error?

Comment: This was me not knowing how to split up all the lines put on one line.  With your clue that I screwed it up I fixed my batch and it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a batch file that contains the following:

```
for /R %%x in (bin) DO del "%%x\\*.*" /Q
```

This will recursively walk through all child directories (from the current directory) and delete all files from every BIN folder.  You could change the `*.*` to whatever file type you'd like to delete.

Comment: Whups sorry I misread.  I put this into a batch file and this seems to spit out a bunch of `del x\*.* /Q` which results in "The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: You are seeing the result of the "Del" command on every "Bin" directory.  I think it gives the message "The system cannot find the file specified" when the "Bin" directory is empty.

Comment: the files in the bin folders are not being deleted though.  I think this depends on there being an unbroken hierarchy of `bin` folders maybe?  the starting directory has no direct descendants that are `bin`.

Comment: You could try this:


@ECHO OFF

for /R %%x in (.) do call:myExistFunc %%x
GOTO:EOF

:myExistFunc
if exist %~1\.\bin call:myDeleteFunc %%~1\bin
GOTO:EOF

:myDeleteFunc
echo. Deleting files from %~1
del %~1\*.* /Q
GOTO EOF

Comment: hmm... this looks closer still but it is not working; did I format it correctly?  (look at my edited question).

Comment: The command given in this answer doesn't work because of a typo: there's only one percentage sign in the second reference to x, where there should be two.  You should also be quoting the path though, as per my answer, and it is probably preferable to check for the existence of each directory before issuing the delete command.

Comment: You should put the text in your answer.  The way you had it in the comment made it very difficult to read.

Answer (score 2):

This should work in a batch file:

```
for /R %%x in (bin) do if exist "%%x" del /q "%%x\*.*"
```

If running this command directly from the command line, replace all instances of `%%x` with just `%x`.

Answer (score 1):

It's been awhile since I've had use any DOS but..

```
DEL BIN\*.*
```

That should delete the files in the directory named BIN below the current directory.

Comment: This does not search the directory tree.

Answer (score 0):

You should write a bat file:

```
for /r %%f in (*) do 'WHATEVER YOU WANT TO DO'
```